# Исчезла первая буква в имени подключаемого файла

Tags: php

При попытке подключения файла RouteController.php на сайте появляется ошибка "Неверное имя файла для подключения - outeController". Я пробежался TotalCommander по всем директориям и не нашёл использования outeController. То есть ошибки в написании нет. В чём может быть причина подобного? 
Для подключения использую это.

```
function autoloadMainClasses($class_name) {
    $class_name = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
    if(!include_once $class_name . '.php') {
        throw new RouteException ('Неверное имя файла для подключения - ' . $class_name);
    }
}
```

Сама же RouteException представляет собой лишь наследницу класса Extension без дополнительных методов и переменных.

Comment: Где и каким образом вызывается функция autoloadMainClasses? Что туда передается?

Comment: В подключаемом через require_once файле. Напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Исключение, как я понимаю, бросает ваша функция `autoloadMainClasses`. Посмотрите какой `$class_name` в неё приходит. Возможно перед вызовом вы как-то обрабатываете имя класса.

Ну а как поборете ошибку, подумайте вот над чем: зачем вы реализуете свой автозагрузчик? Есть стандартные [PSR-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) и их поддерживает [композер](https://getcomposer.org). Судя по коду вам подойдёт любой из них.

Comment: Действительно. В '$class_name' приходит 'outeController'. Буду пытаться понять. Реализую чисто попробовать. Этот сайт в текущем виде никогда не будет использоваться где-то кроме моего локального сервера. Спасибо Вам, Нашёл ошибку!

Comment: @FridenCraw Если разбираетесь, то обратите внимание на такой интересный момент. Если класс не найден, то php выбросит стандартную ошибку в том месте, где использовался класс. В вашей реализации будет выброшено исключение совсем из другого места. Кроме того, при включенных варнингах ещё и include споткнётся. Можно не бросать исключение из своего загрузчика, а попытаться зарезолвить имя файла (`stream_resolve_include_path`) и только если такой файл существует, то подключить его (исключения кидать не надо).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!